# Unable to run Sonarqube analysis from cloudbuild.yaml with Google Cloud build

Tags: triggers, sonarqube

I have integrated my github repo with Google cloud build to automatically build a docker images after every commit in github. This is working fine, but now I want to do sonarqube analysis on code before Docker image building process. So for that I have integrated the sonarqube part in cloudbuild.yaml file. But not able to run it.

I have followed the steps provided in link:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/sonarqube

and pushed the sonar-scanner image in google container registry.
My sonarqube server is running on a GCP instance. On every commit in github, cluod build automatically triggered and start doing task mentioned in cloudbuild.yaml file

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM nginx
    COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

cloudbuild.yaml :

```
    steps:

    - name: 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/sonar-scanner:latest'
        args:
        - '-Dsonar.host.url=sonarqube_url'
        - '-Dsonar.login=c2a7631a6e402c338739091ffbc30e5e3d66cf19'
        - '-Dsonar.projectKey=sample-project'
        - '-Dsonar.sources=.'

    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/html-css-website', '.' ]

    images:
    - 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/html-css-website'
```

Error:

```
Status: Build failed
Status detail: failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: yaml: line 3: did not find expected key
```

Comment: Please enclose your YAML content in appropriate formatting tags: the error indicates your YAML is wrong but it's impossible to read it with the current formatting.

Comment: Thanks @mc1arke , The formatting was correct. It was just typing issue here. Here PROJECT_ID indicates my actual GCP project id and sonarqube_url iindicates the actual url of my sonarqube instance

Comment: @AnkitSoni Hi. May I ask regarding "My sonarqube server is running on a GCP instance." is your instance on private or public netowork? Is it reachable from the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the formatting you've pasted actually matches what you've got in your project then your issue is that the `args` property within the first `steps` block is indented too far: it should be aligned with the `name` property above it.

```
--- 
steps: 
  - name: "gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/sonar-scanner:latest"
    args: 
      - "-Dsonar.host.url=sonarqube_url"
      - "-Dsonar.login=c2a7631a6e402c338739091ffbc30e5e3d66cf19"
      - "-Dsonar.projectKey=sample-project"
      - "-Dsonar.sources=."
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: 
      - "build"
      - "-t"
      - "gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/html-css-website"
      - "."
images: 
  - "gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/html-css-website"
```

Comment: Thanks, The issue got resloved.